# Inclusive tax always shows as £0.00 in breakdown

Tags: magento-1.7, tax

All the products on my site are inclusive of tax.

However at the cart and checkout stage and also any invoices I'd still like to be able to display what the tax portion was.

Like this site.

[image: Inclusive tax shows breakdown]

The Total is still just £75.05 + £3.99 delivery, but it's good to show the customer what the tax portion was.

Unfortunately on my site magento keeps showing the tax value as £0.00:

[image: Tax breakdown shows 0.00]

I'm using Magento Community Edition 1.7.

I have setup my tax details as follows:

**System > Conifguration > Sales > Tax**
[image: System Config Sales tax]

**Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules**
[image: Sales Tax Manage Tax Rules]

**Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones and Rates**
[image]

**Product > General**
[image: Product settings]

Is there anything obvious I'm overlooking?

Comment: What is your shipping origin (System > Configuration > Shipping Settings > Origin)?

Comment: You are spot on - that is exactly what it was. Makes sense. So much to check when setting up tax the mind becomes pickled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set tax calculation to be based on Shipping Origin. This needs to be configured under System > Configuration > Shipping Settings > Origin